# Is a bile jar guaranteed to spawn before map 4's crescendo event in Dark Carnival?

Tags: left-4-dead-2

In Dark Carnival, a bile jar comes in really handy at the end of map 4, *the Farms*, for passing the gates and going upstream the flow of zombies without taking too much damage. Of course, most noobs, if they have a bile jar, tend to waste it before that critical moment -_-' but that's not the issue...

My question is: is at least one bile jar guaranteed to spawn somewhere in Dark Carnival before map 4's crescendo event, in every instance of that campaign?

Comment: Is any item ever guarateed to spawn in L4D2?

Comment: @Alex I don't know the details of their "spawn" algorithm, but there seems to be some *hard* constraints, like "during a compaign, spawn a tank in at least one map". I'm wondering if that kind of rule applies to the spawning of bile jars in Dark Carnival...

Comment: I think that is does NOT spawn in any level except the first and last. I don't know if it is guaranteed to spawn in level one, but I do know it commonly does. Most people do not look hard enough in the motel rooms, but I often see it at the HUMV on the highway approach.

Comment: @Alex In my experience the M60 *always* spawns in one of three places on the subway map (2nd) of No Mercy: either the dead-end track tunnel as you come up the first escalator on the left, the right side tunnel after the fire, or in the right side alley as you exit back onto the street (next to the trash bags).

Comment: Some item spawns are guaranteed at fixed locations, for example the medkits in the 2nd level of the parish. I can't think of any -guaranteed- spawns in that particular level though.

Comment: Well, you will always see a guitar at the stage in Dark Carnival finale.

Answer (score 4):

A friend and myself ran DC on expert (trying for the achievement) for months. Most of the time, we got a single bile jar towards the beginning of the first map, but aside from that, no, it's not guaranteed. There were several (and it was like 15-20% of the time) that NO bile jar spawned at all, making that gate run near impossible. Knowing it's importance, we'd always keep an eye out for the jar, and seems highly unlikely that we'd just miss it that many times.